# x64 applications using gdi+: what are the consequences on performance?

Tags: .net, performance, gdi+, 64-bit

I am currently implementing an ASP.Net application which is using GDI+ to do server-side rendering. First versions were dependent on a 32 bits unmanaged component, so all the managed assembly were compiled for x86 platform. Lastly I got rid of this dependency and am now able to set the target platform to AnyCPU. Since the application can potentially be used to handle a lot of data, being able to run it in 64 bits may be useful. However I read there is a performance decrease when using GDI+ on x64 platform, but was not able to have detailed information about it.

What are the performance issues I should be aware of in order to know if running in 64 bits worth the performance cost?

Comment: First I heard of it, never seen a perf problem myself.  GDI+ is just a chunk of native code.  Wikipedia would tag this [citation required].

Comment: Same here, never heard of a problem with 64-bit GDI+. If you have a worry, compile two versions and test them. Watch memory and CPU usage and look for any memory leaks. If you do that, regardless of your results, post it back here so we can help answer when the next question comes along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I had wrong information: after profiling a GDI+ application compiled both for x86 and x64 it appears that the performance are the same for each platform. I do not remember where I read that first, but it is a good reminder of the "assume nothing before seeing" moto.
It's good to have a definitive answer to my question though!